# Import other child classes from same submodule within constructor of base class

Tags: python, python-import

Given the following folder structure:

```
train
|__base
|  |__model.py
|  |__layer.py
|
|__nb
|  |__model.py
|  |__layer.py
|
|__norm
|  |__model.py
|  |__layer.py
```

nb and norm contain models and layers specific to an nb and a norm distribution, respectively.
The classes `Model` and `Layer` in these two folders are children of the respective classes in the base folder.
Let's say, an instance of `Model` contains an instance of `Layer` and `model.layer` must of course be from the same folder.
But I need to call the model's super constructor from `base.model.py` and create the distribution specific layer there.

I could do sth. like this in the base model constructor:

```py
__init__(self, distribution, **kwargs):
    if distribution == 'nb':
        from nb.layer import Layer
    elif distribution == 'norm':
        from norm.layer import Layer
    else:
        assert False, "Unrecognized distribution."
    self.layer = Layer()
```

Now I need to know all distributions in the base model and hardcode the passed distribution string. But my tool needs to be extendable, thus I do not know which additional distributions are added in the future. I'd like to find a fancy solution that enables it to automatically detect from which subfolder is has to import, based on which child model the base model constructor has been called from (i.e. if the norm model is created, the base model should also import the norm layer, not the nb layer).

Is there any way to get around it?
The perfect solution would work without passing any additional argument like `distribution` to the base constructor.
But even if it is necessary to pass `distribution`, is it possible to somehow pass the right path to the nb/norm subfolder and do sth. like `from <distribution>.layer import Layer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is to use `importlib.import_module`:

```py
from importlib import import_module


class Model:
    __init__(self, distribution_module: str):
        layers = import_module(name='...' + distribution_module + '.layers', package=__name__)
        self.layer = layers.Layer()
```

`distribution_module` must be named after the submodule, (i.e. 'norm' or 'nb' in this case). Depending on the folder structure, the relative path with respect to `package` must be appended by points (i.e. '...' in this case, because `__name__` is 'train.base.model').
One can also discard the `package` arg if supplying an absolute path.

See documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module